# SCSS auto-suggestion on VS code

Tags: css, visual-studio-code, sass, scss-lint

I am new to `SCSS` and have just started a new project, as you can see below I have declared 4 variables in Global.scss but after import it to another scss file, I was unable to get any auto-suggestion as I was assigning those variables.

Am I missing any plugins? Or any other way to solve this?

[image]

Comment: If you import partials file without underscore `_filename.scss` sass compile it directly, so you have to need to import partial files with an underscore. [Example](https://www.w3schools.com/sass/sass_import.asp#:~:text=sass%20or%20.,used%20in%20the%20main%20file.)

Comment: @Momin thanks for your reply, I have added _Global.scss now but still there are no auto suggestion from VS code. Any other reason?

Comment: If you import the file correctly, variable or any suggestions should be IntelliSense of VS Code or WebStorm IDE features. [Install](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=mrmlnc.vscode-scss) it on vs code

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Besides [SCSS intelliSense](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=mrmlnc.vscode-scss), you can also try [SCSS Everywhere](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=gencer.html-slim-scss-css-class-completion) which gives you suggestions when you are assigning classes to HTML elements.

[image]

Comment: Great answer (I upvoted). For anyone using SCSS Intellisense VS Code extension, (and using an npm library like `@angular/material`) you may need to change the settings, specifically the `"scss.scannerExclude"` settings, to a) remove "**/node_modules" from the list (so *stop excluding* `node_modules` = include it), or b) exclude only *certain* node_modules from the list, as shown [here](https://github.com/mrmlnc/vscode-scss/issues/77#issuecomment-587482478)  and kinda shown [here](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/869#issuecomment-630086813).

Answer (score 6):

Yes, You need to install a `vs code extension`.[SCSS IntelliSense](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=mrmlnc.vscode-scss)

Installing this extension will show suggestions for variables accessed in a different file.

Comment: Great answer (I upvoted, but it's redundant with the accepted answer, isn't it?). If you use SCSS Intellisense extension, (and using an npm library like `@angular/material`) you may need to change the settings, specifically the `"scss.scannerExclude"` settings, to a) remove "**/node_modules" from the list (so *stop excluding* `node_modules` = include it), or b) exclude only *certain* node_modules from the list, as shown [here](https://github.com/mrmlnc/vscode-scss/issues/77#issuecomment-587482478)  and kinda shown [here](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/869#issuecomment-630086813).

Comment: @NateAnderson thank you for mentioning scss.scannerExcludes setting.  I am evaluating if I need to keep Bulma (scss version) in a project I will work on this coming year.  It is a small to medium project (2 GAs and a single programmer).  Your setting suggestion goes a long way to me getting rid of an unnecessary framework.